# Trouble with "No authentication challenges found" when trying to get the data from server

Tags: java, android, httpconnection, openweathermap

I want to get the data from server but when I ran the app , it showed "Error java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found ", I don't know how to fix this

here's my logcat

```
Error java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found 
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getAuthorizationCredentials(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:436)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:416)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:365)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:301)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
at com.project.mluan.sunshine.FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(FetchWeatherTask.java:391)
at com.project.mluan.sunshine.FetchWeatherTask.doInBackground(FetchWeatherTask.java:48)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

and this is my method http://pastebin.com/ndZZFh7L

Comment: did you add the internet permission?

Comment: yes, I already have it, the app run normally until I changed to use content provider

Comment: maybe you should change back

Comment: but I'm taking android course from udacity, if my app doesn't works then I can't move to the next lesson

Comment: have you added api key?